# why 4 in TCP timeout formula

Tags: network-programming

In the formula for TCP timeout calculation we multiply 4 with Deviation, my question is that why we multiply 4 and not any other number with the deviation? please tell.

**FORMULA**

```
Timeout_Interval = Estimated_RTT + 4*(Deviation_RTT)
```

Comment: Because [van Jacobsen suggested it in 1988](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sylvia/papers/congavoid.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

If you think of [standard deviations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation), then +1σ will cover about 84.1%, +2σ will cover about 97.7%, +3σ will cover about 99.8%, and +4σ will cover about 99.9%.

The "Deviation_RTT" is much the same and thus this equation will avoid retransmission for the vast majority of packets that are sent.  You can make it larger to have slightly fewer retransmissions but also be slower to pull the trigger when a packet does get lost.